# How do I create a directed graph in networkx from a dictionary?

Tags: python, networkx

I have ~10k publications that have inbound or/and outbound citations.

Data comes in the following format (two entries as an example):

```
# each 'number' is a 'paper_id'
citations = {
    '157553241': { 
        'inbound_citations': [],
        'outbound_citations': [
            '141919793',
            '158546657',
            '156580052',
            '159778536',
            '157021328',
            '158546657',
            '157021328',
            '141919793',
            '153005744',
            '159778536',
            '112335878',
            '156580052'
        ]
    },
    '54196724': {
        'inbound_citations': ['204753337', '55910675'],
        'outbound_citations': ['153776751', '141060228', '33718066', '158233543']
    },
}
```

How do I transform this format into something I could feed to `networkx`?

I'd like to find the most 'central' papers & discover some cliques (to begin with).

I've tried

```py
G = nx.DiGraph(citations)
```

but I don't think it works like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a list of edges like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

edges = []
for node in citations:
    for parent in citations[node]['inbound_citations']:
        edges.append((parent, node))
    for child in citations[node]['outbound_citations']:
        edges.append((node, child))

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]